# Flex PMD not Working anytime?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5, flex-pmd

i am surprising after seeing the result of FlexPMD. i installed FlexPMD as [zoltanb](http://zoltanb.co.uk/how-to-install-flexpmd-in-flex-builder-4-5/) said me. I have a Project with 2500 Files approximately and as I remember, i had a lots of duplicate code and not commented code means that a line is commented which call a function so Whole function commented Automatically so Why PMD not Gives a Result or any output in FlexPMD tab?

If you have any Idea, please Help me...

Comment: I have the same issue. Although it did work at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Researching, we find some point to resolve this problem:

**1. Your Project Path do not contain any space.**

**2. Your Flex SDK must opened in Administrative Mode.**

here My Problem is that My Project path contain a space  **D:\Facebook apps** after changing it to **D:\Facebookapps**, i have solution.

May this Works For you @The_asMan